# Javascript; check if a variable is 1 or 0

Tags: php, javascript

I'm using a variable in Javascript which will be set via Php e.g. `var usesInterview = <?php echo 1;?>`

If not, then `var usesInterview = <?php echo 0;?>`

How best should I handle this in my code? There will be a If statement to check for the variable and determine the route to take.

I've tried using `typeof() == 1` and when I set it to 0, it still carries out the routine as if it where 1.

Comment: Did you find any of the answers usefull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways you can do it... Ie

```
var usesInterview = <?php echo [0|1];?>
usesInterview ? goingTrueWay() : goingFalsegWay();
```

or

```
<?php echo [0|1];?> ? goingTrueWay() : goingFalseWay();
```

or something like this:

```
var waysCollection = {
    0: function () {...} //routine for usesInterview == 0
    1: function () {...} //routine for usesInterview == 1
}
waysCollection[<?php echo [0|1];?>]();
```

also you can use one of the early suggestion:

```
if (<?php echo [0|1];?>) {
  // truthy branch
} else {
  // falsy branch
}
```

BTW, if you want `usesInterview` to be a boolean, yes/no trigger, - use `true`/`false` not `0`/`1`. Its easier to read and understand later. For ex

```
var usesInterview = <?php echo [false|true];?>
if (usesInterview) {
  //do this if `true`
} else {
  //do this if `false`
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not set it with javascript:

```
usesInterview = 1;
```

Even if you set it with PHP, you can check like this:

```
if (usesInterview === 1){
  // variable is equal to 1
}
else if (usesInterview === 0){
  // variable is equal to 0
}
```

Notice the `===` to check for both **type** as well as **value**. If you don't want to check for type, you need to use `==` like this:

```
if (usesInterview == 1){
  // variable is equal to 1 or "1" or true
}
else if (usesInterview == 0){
  // variable is equal to 0 or "0" or "" or false
}
```

You should avoid the later approach when you are sure about both **type** as well as **value**.

**More Information:**

- http://w3schools.com/JS/js_comparisons.asp

Comment: Because it will be a Php variable that will determine if the use has interviews. I can't set a Javascript variable in a Php script but I can set a javascript variable in a template using Php.

Comment: @Sarfraz Using a non-strict comparison operator with a zero value (as in `x == 0`) should be avoided. Values that produce true are 0, "", "0", false, etc.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Agreed, a reason why I have posted the better solution on top and later one too just in case :)

Comment: @Sarfraz If you want to keep the later solution (as part of your answer), you obviously have to update the comments in the blocks... The else-branch comment should be: `// variable is equal to 0 or "0" or "" or false`. The if-branch comment: `// variable is equal to 1 or "1" or true`. (I believe that there are also other values that have to be mentioned, but I'm not sure (from the top of my head)).

Comment: @Sarfraz I think that it would also be wise to **actually mention** that such a construct should be avoided. Also, you might mention that it will produce an error in JSLint.

Answer (score 1):

`typeof` will return the type of the value - `"number"` in this case.  You're using a non-strict equality check (`==`) so `"number" == 1` is `true`.

Just check the value, using type-strict equality operator (`===`):

```
if (usesInterview === 1) {
    // do something
}
else if (usesInterview === 0) {
    // do something else
}
```

Read more about JavaScript comparison operators at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators.

Answer (score 0):

When `usesInterview` is 1 it's [truthy](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript). So it's as simple as:

```
if (usesInterview) {
  // truthy branch
} else {
  // falsy branch
}
```